# Raspberry Pi Software Driven servo control with PWM using C and Wiring Pi LIbrary

Tags: pwm, c, wiringpi, servo

I'm trying to get my raspi zero to move an SG90 PWM driven servo. I have achieved this with python already using the gpiozero library, so I know my hardware works but I am trying to do it with C using the wiringPi library. when I compile and run the executable (using sudo) I get no errors and everything seems to work, but the servo doesn't move at all.

I assumed I was using the wrong pin number at first. I found this post [Raspberry pi Software Driven PWM using C++](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/61043/raspberry-pi-software-driven-pwm-using-c) and I used the table offered in one of the answers. The pin I'm using is physical pin 11, the 6th pin up from the square pin 1, aka GPIO17. I've tried using 11 with wiringPiSetupPhys(), 17 with wiringPiSetupGpio(), and 0 with wiringPiSetup(), getting the same result each time. I initially tried writing 50 and then changed it to 10000, but both times got nothing

here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <softPwm.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define PWM_PIN_NUM 17

int main(){

  if(wiringPiSetupGpio()){
    printf("Failed to setup wiringPi\n");
  }

  pinMode(PWM_PIN_NUM, OUTPUT);

  if(softPwmCreate(PWM_PIN_NUM, 0, 100)){
    printf("Failed to init pwm pin\n");
  }

  printf("Successfully setup wiringPi and init pwm pin\n");

  softPwmWrite(PWM_PIN_NUM, 10000);

  sleep(1);
  
  printf("%s: %d\n", strerror(errno), errno);
}
```

it always outputs "sucessfully setup etc etc" and errno is always 0

Comment: A servo requires pulses at 50 Hz.  Each pulse should be between say 600 to 2400 µs long for a SG90.  How are you ensuring these values?

Comment: Thanks for responding! No Idea, I'm definitely not an expert at the nitty gritty details of servo control, but I have a standard pi zero, and I was hoping the wiringPi library would be able to handle those details. I wrote 10000 because someone on the linked post said that softPwmWrite() clips values to the highest possible value to be written to the servo, in this case 100, which if I understand correctly, would encode a 2400 µs pulse and cause the servo to rotate 180 degrees.

Comment: another thing of note is that I got a similar response with the gpio command line utility, although I know very little about the utility and was relying on a tutorial, just to test my soldering. I've only been able to get the servo to move with the python gpiozero library, somehow it knows something I don't

Comment: I'm not a fan of software timed PWM for servos.  If you must use software timed PWM from C I suggest you use my [lgpio library](http://abyz.me.uk/lg/index.html) and [lgTxServo](http://abyz.me.uk/lg/lgpio.html#lgTxServo).  For hardware timed PWM use pigpio (e.g. `sudo pigpiod` then `pigs s 17 1000`, `pigs s 17 2000` to move your servo.

Comment: Okay I'll check it out. Do you know what's wrong here though? I assume if I write this exact same code using your library I will probably get the same result until I figure out what's going on here

Comment: I'd have to read the wiringPi documentation for those calls to see what you re doing wrong.  You can do that as easily as me.http://wiringpi.com/reference/software-pwm-library/

Comment: Okay, in that case I can try to use your library to recreate it so that if I get the same error you will understand what is going wrong. Do I need both Igpio and IgTxServo?

Comment: If pigs works then the servo is okay and any library will work.  lgTxServo is part of the lgpio library.

Comment: oh no okay so pigs works which is nice, but now my c code works sometimes and not other times and I have no clue why. It seems that it works very infrequently and only after sudo pigpiod is run. Also after running pigs s 17 1000 or 2000, my already working python code gets really buggered up, like the servo shakes a lot and doesn't move that much. It seems I don't have a good enough understanding about how the servo is controlled

Comment: Is it inefficient to just use system() or exec() and execute pigs calls rather than using a c library?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure something out, however I was not able to get it to work with the wiringPi library. I used the linux sysfs interface to control the gpio pin directly and then I created my own sofware timed pwm. I used the information in this link https://www.ics.com/blog/how-control-gpio-hardware-c-or-c. I hope this doesn't become a dead link in the future, it is super helpful information. I created a c++ class that resembled the wiringPi library and used sysfs to implement the functions myself. If anyone needs more information on this, leave a comment or ask a question and tag me and I will be happy to elaborate and show my code.

Comment: If you "have achieved this with python already using the gpiozero library" which is by default based on [RPi.GPIO](https://pypi.org/project/RPi.GPIO/) there seems little reason to write new code based on the deprecated sysfs interface or attempting to emulate the deprecated WiringPi code.

Comment: I have made my own version of RPi.GPIO and am in the process of extracting the underlying code to make a C library. This is working, but incomplete.
There are other PWM libraries, including [lgpio](http://abyz.me.uk/lg/lgpio.html) which is a new C library for Linux Single Board Computers (including the Pi) which allows control of the GPIO.

Comment: Awesome! I just wanted to implement it in C++ because I am trying to learn embedded programming with c++. Do you know if the igpio library uses the sysfs interface under the hood?

Comment: AFAIK No current libraries use the deprecated sysfs interface. Most use `gpiomem` to access the hardware registers. Joan's new code uses the [gpiochip](https://www.beyondlogic.org/an-introduction-to-chardev-gpio-and-libgpiod-on-the-raspberry-pi/) interface.